# No recaptcha in POST var being sent

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

The code below is the code for my form on my webpage, then test.php.  The issue is there is no recaptcha var being sent in the $_POST.  I have ensured the tag for the recaptcha is with in the form tag, the call to googles .js is in the head.  I cannot find the reason my form is not sending the var.

```
<head>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>


<div id="contact" class="form-contain">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="message"></div>
            <form method="post" action="js/test.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
                 <div class="form-group">
                      <input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <input name="email" id="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" value="" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control" />
                 </div>

                 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcMRQ0UAAAAACB1GVYh0oIQezzFcNmpsy0a7Sqx"></div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="submit">Send</button>
                  </div>
             </form>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
    $email;$comment;$captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
      $email=$_POST['email'];
    }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
      $email=$_POST['comment'];
    }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
      exit;
    }
    $secretKey = "Put your secret key here";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
    if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
      echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
    } else {
      echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not set and is not just blank or otherwise invalid? If you try executing `echo isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) ? "true" : "false";`, what is being outputted?

Comment: @bugfroggy I checked by adding echo var_dump($_POST); and it returned

array(4) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Zack Tarr" ["email"]=> string(28) "ztarr@sy...." ["phone"]=> string(10) "812...." ["comments"]=> string(1) "message" }

Comment: On your site, check the reCAPTCHA box but don't submit the form. Inspect element and look for a textarea with the ID "g-recaptcha-response" in your form. It should be somewhere in the `div` with class `g-recaptcha`. Proper structure should be like this: http://i.imgur.com/4A6q3Ao.png Does it exist inside the form tags? If so, change its CSS so it is no longer `display: none` and you can view its contents easily. Does it have a value inside?

Comment: @bugfroggy  I will try to check that. If you want to take a look at the site you can check it out here zacktarrcreations.com/AFK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your website that you provided in the comments, I noticed your submit form handler is only submitting 4 fields (`name`, `email`, `phone`, and `comments`). This needs to be modified to include `g-recaptcha-response`.

From http://zacktarrcreations.com/AFK/js/plugins.js on line 1141:

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#message").slideUp(500,function() {
            $('#message').hide();

            $.post(action, {
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    phone: $('#phone').val(),
                    comments: $('#comments').val(),
                },
                function(data){
                    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                    $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

                }
            );

        });

        return false;

    });
```

Change to:

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#message").slideUp(500,function() {
            $('#message').hide();

            $.post(action, {
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    phone: $('#phone').val(),
                    comments: $('#comments').val(),
                    "g-recaptcha-response": $('#g-recaptcha-response').val(),
                },
                function(data){
                    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                    $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

                }
            );

        });

        return false;

    });
```

Tested and it worked for me.